# PNGs not being generated for VectorDrawable

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I am using VectorDrawables in my app. But On pre-lollipop devices, the VectorDrawables appear blurry. I have read that vector drawables are not supported on these devices. And gradle plug-in automatically generates PNGs for each VectorDrawable.

But in my project, the PNGs are not being generated.

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the vector drawable's Height and Width according to the height required for the view.
A vector drawable  with width and height 24dp each will look blur when you will set it as source for the `ImageView` having height and width 300dp each on both above L device and below L devices. But when you set the vector drawable as background on a view it will stretch as per the drawables width and height above L devices only.

The vector drawable-

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M7.52,21.48C4.25,19.94 1.91,16.76 1.55,13H0.05C0.56,19.16 5.71,24 12,24l0.66,-0.03 -3.81,-3.81 -1.33,1.32z
        m0.89,-6.52c-0.19,0 -0.37,-0.03 -0.52,-0.08 -0.16,-0.06 -0.29,-0.13 -0.4,-0.24 -0.11,-0.1 -0.2,-0.22 -0.26,-0.37 -0.06,-0.14 -0.09,-0.3 -0.09,-0.47h-1.3c0,0.36 0.07,0.68 0.21,0.95 0.14,0.27 0.33,0.5 0.56,0.69 0.24,0.18 0.51,0.32 0.82,0.41 0.3,0.1 0.62,0.15 0.96,0.15 0.37,0 0.72,-0.05 1.03,-0.15 0.32,-0.1 0.6,-0.25 0.83,-0.44s0.42,-0.43 0.55,-0.72c0.13,-0.29 0.2,-0.61 0.2,-0.97 0,-0.19 -0.02,-0.38 -0.07,-0.56 -0.05,-0.18 -0.12,-0.35 -0.23,-0.51 -0.1,-0.16 -0.24,-0.3 -0.4,-0.43 -0.17,-0.13 -0.37,-0.23 -0.61,-0.31 0.2,-0.09 0.37,-0.2 0.52,-0.33 0.15,-0.13 0.27,-0.27 0.37,-0.42 0.1,-0.15 0.17,-0.3 0.22,-0.46 0.05,-0.16 0.07,-0.32 0.07,-0.48 0,-0.36 -0.06,-0.68 -0.18,-0.96 -0.12,-0.28 -0.29,-0.51 -0.51,-0.69 -0.2,-0.19 -0.47,-0.33 -0.77,-0.43C9.1,8.05 8.76,8 8.39,8c-0.36,0 -0.69,0.05 -1,0.16 -0.3,0.11 -0.57,0.26 -0.79,0.45 -0.21,0.19 -0.38,0.41 -0.51,0.67 -0.12,0.26 -0.18,0.54 -0.18,0.85h1.3c0,-0.17 0.03,-0.32 0.09,-0.45s0.14,-0.25 0.25,-0.34c0.11,-0.09 0.23,-0.17 0.38,-0.22 0.15,-0.05 0.3,-0.08 0.48,-0.08 0.4,0 0.7,0.1 0.89,0.31 0.19,0.2 0.29,0.49 0.29,0.86 0,0.18 -0.03,0.34 -0.08,0.49 -0.05,0.15 -0.14,0.27 -0.25,0.37 -0.11,0.1 -0.25,0.18 -0.41,0.24 -0.16,0.06 -0.36,0.09 -0.58,0.09H7.5v1.03h0.77c0.22,0 0.42,0.02 0.6,0.07s0.33,0.13 0.45,0.23c0.12,0.11 0.22,0.24 0.29,0.4 0.07,0.16 0.1,0.35 0.1,0.57 0,0.41 -0.12,0.72 -0.35,0.93 -0.23,0.23 -0.55,0.33 -0.95,0.33z
        m8.55,-5.92c-0.32,-0.33 -0.7,-0.59 -1.14,-0.77 -0.43,-0.18 -0.92,-0.27 -1.46,-0.27H12v8h2.3c0.55,0 1.06,-0.09 1.51,-0.27 0.45,-0.18 0.84,-0.43 1.16,-0.76 0.32,-0.33 0.57,-0.73 0.74,-1.19 0.17,-0.47 0.26,-0.99 0.26,-1.57v-0.4c0,-0.58 -0.09,-1.1 -0.26,-1.57 -0.18,-0.47 -0.43,-0.87 -0.75,-1.2z
        m-0.39,3.16c0,0.42 -0.05,0.79 -0.14,1.13 -0.1,0.33 -0.24,0.62 -0.43,0.85 -0.19,0.23 -0.43,0.41 -0.71,0.53 -0.29,0.12 -0.62,0.18 -0.99,0.18h-0.91V9.12h0.97c0.72,0 1.27,0.23 1.64,0.69 0.38,0.46 0.57,1.12 0.57,1.99v0.4z
        "/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,0l-0.66,0.03 3.81,3.81 1.33,-1.33c3.27,1.55 5.61,4.72 5.96,8.48h1.5C23.44,4.84 18.29,0 12,0z"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,0l-0.66,0.03 3.81,3.81 1.33,-1.33c3.27,1.55 5.61,4.72 5.96,8.48h1.5C23.44,4.84 18.29,0 12,0z"/>
</vector>
```

On 5.O+ looks like this-(top one (match_parent*300dp) as src for imageview and bottom one(200dp*200dp) as background)

[image]

And below 5.0 (On 5.O+ looks like this-(top one (match_parent*300dp) as src for imageview and bottom one(200dp*200dp) as background))

[image]

But When I set the vector drawable's width and height to 300 dp each then on the both above 5.0 and blew 5.0 it looks clear.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been using vector drawables since AS 1.4 and in AS 1.5 and around it has stopped showing png drawables in folder, Show i have try to run app in lower devices.It was showing drawables perfectly. 
According to [Documetation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html) they have changed in png folder and Now they are add in **generated folder** in **build**.

Check out

> app-->build-->generated-->res-->debug

[image: PNG]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the generated PNGs. 
But the generated PNGs are blurred too,

Comment: @GaganSaini please read their documentation. They have provided new info.